# Bundeled file names referencing to line numbers in console when using parceljs with simple Html, css, js

Tags: javascript, reload, parceljs

I am using parceljs for hot-reloading and bundling, when I console something using JavaScript and then go to the localhost to see console, i see some weird js file names for referencing error and console line numbers. e.g. script.75da7f30.js:180:11 . I want my local file line numbers not the bundled ones. How can I do that ?

Problem: In browser console, i see the bundeled file names (like script.75da7f30.js:180:11 ) giving reference to the line numbers for errors in code or in order to log something in console.

I want the console to show the file names of origin files (that i am writing code to) instead of the minified/bundeled files of parcel. I need to see my files bcz if browser console give me some sort of error then I would go to that line in code editor and try to remove that error.